# Propagating a Beer Yeast Culture to other applications

Tags: taste, yeast

How much of an impact do yeasts strains have on their [beer] products?  Is this a significant game changer?

I want to craft delicious fermented foods. Beer, bread and pizza are a few of my motives.

I have various (German) beers I absolutely love that I would like to propagate a culture of yeast from to make these foods and beverages.  With the impression that these tasty beer's yeast cultures could be a factor that would reflect in the tastiness of these products.

My concerns are how much of a difference propagating such yeast strains are VS. other factors of the product's various ingredients.  Mainly, Will I notice a big difference in the individual yeast cultures alone, aside from the other ingredient factors?
Or does it not matter as much as the other ingredients?

Comment: This question may get more traction on the Homebrew SE site.

Comment: Ahh I've yet to discover, till now... thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 2):

Yeast can change everything in a beer.

The french brewery `le père l'amer` released 2 beers (or 4) on which they brewed one batch of beer, splitted it in 2 and put one yeast on the first part and an other yeast on the second.

This made 2 beers who looked, smelled and tasted completely differently (and they did not have the same percentage of alcohol too).

Here they are on untappd :

[yeast battle #1 verdant](https://untappd.com/b/le-pere-l-amer-yeast-battle-1-verdant/4264010) VS [yeast battle #1 WLP644](https://untappd.com/b/le-pere-l-amer-yeast-battle-1-wlp644/4264219)

[yeast battle #2 dry english](https://untappd.com/b/le-pere-l-amer-yeast-battle-2-dry-english/4365119) VS [yeast battle #2 london fog](https://untappd.com/b/le-pere-l-amer-yeast-battle-2-london-fog/4365116)

Comment: Good answer but did you mean to highlight "le père l'amer" or provide a link. A link would be more useful.

Comment: @Eric s this was just an example I know that proved that just changing the yeast cam change everything. I put untappd links so you van see via the photos and the comments how different the beer are with just the yeast being changed.